# Set Atom Default Window Size

Tags: atom-editor

I am new to Atom but I already fall in love with this editor. There is one problem, however, that bugs me a lot: each time I adjust the window size, I will get the window size maximized when I reopen Atom. This irritates me because I need to re-drag the window again to have the size I like.

Is there any way to set the default window size?